# div border extends padding on top and bottom of div

Tags: javascript, css, html, margin

I have an issue with some CSS shrinkwrapping. First the (very simple) code...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Device Activation</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background: white;
                font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
            }
            div {
                background: #dddddd;
                //border: 1px solid;
                border-radius: 40px;
                box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
                //display: inline-block;
                padding: 0px 10px;
                //text-align: justify;
                //-moz-border-radius: 40px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
            <h1>Boogy-woogy</h1>
        <div id="start" class="toggleable">
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function makeVisible() {
            // Not here yet, but that's okay...right?   
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The issue: When you remove the comments from `border: 1px solid;` the div top and bottom margins will increase significantly.

I have done some research and I understand that this issue relates to collapsing-margins, but I have tried several fixes and nothing seems to effect my end result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your code sample is just a typo. 
If not, then please note that with JavaScript comments, you have the options of:

```
// This is a javascript comment
/* This is a javascript comment as well... */
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Code_comments

If you want to make a CSS comment,
you cannot use the `// this is a comment` snyntax. 
You need to use the `/* this is a comment */` syntax.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#comments

Now, when I hide the `border: 1px solid` line,  I do not see the top or bottom margin changing. But I think what was happening with the improper syntax you used in the code in your question, the `div` was resorting to `display: block` because the `inline-block` rule was not being applied. Because `inline-block` was not being applied, the div stretched to its full width.

http://jsfiddle.net/2f59k/

```
  body {
      background: white;
      font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
  }
  div {
      background: #dddddd;
     /* border: 1px solid;*/
      border-radius: 40px;
      box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
      display: inline-block; 
      padding: 0px 10px;
      text-align: justify;
      -moz-border-radius: 40px;
  }
```

Again, if nothing else is gleaned from this answer,
this is **not** a CSS comment:

```
// border: 1px solid;
```

This **is** a CSS comment:

```
/* border: 1px solid; */
```

---

UPDATE

This issue has nothing to do with border radius, borders, etc. Your problem, if understood solely as the amount of space above and below the text, yet inside the grey background, is that the **margin** surrounding the text. 
This increase is significant, but not nearly as significant as the change in the width when the div goes between `block` and `inline-block`.

Setting the `margin` of the inner paragraph to `margin: 0` resolves the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/74eTg/

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help me with this. Your answer was informative, detailed, and most of all, you pointed out my embarrassing CSS syntax user error without making me feel like too much of a fool. >.< You are the reason that Stack Overflow is so great. :)

Answer (score 3):

i think what you mean is because the p has got default margins and padding. add

```
p {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

to the css

Comment: Thank you for the post. You are absolutely correct. I chose the other answer simply because the author went into more detail on some of my other errors, but I can respect to-the-point answers too. +1 to you good sir or madam. :)